# td:nth-child change order of td

Tags: html, css

I have this table and I would like the second td to show on top of the first one when I size down the screen.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 872px) {
td :nth-child(1) {display:bottom}


td :nth-child(2) {display:top}

}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
   dhklsadhfjl;skdjflskdjfzx,nc,zmxnv;lkjdfsd;lakfjas,nxc
</td>
    <td><div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">

  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="1ma63N35/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="1ma63N35/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="1ma63N35/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="1ma63N35/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="1ma63N35/5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 872px) {
td :nth-child(1) {display:bottom}

td :nth-child(2) {display:top}

}

Comment: `bottom` and `top` are invalid `display` values.

Comment: And it doesn't look like tabular data either. Are you using `table` for layout here?

Comment: if you want layouting not for data, use css-grid. Even flexboxes would work. There you can declare the order or placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to do is the use of a css-grid. it does a tabular like styling without limitations or the heavy coding of a table. With grid-area youc an easily change a listing order.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(min-content, 500px);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 200px) 
  and (max-width: 872px) {
    .grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:
        "pictures"
        "text";
    }
    
    .pictures {
      grid-area: pictures;
    }
    
    .text {
      grid-area: text;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="text">
   dhklsadhfjl; skdjflskdjfzx, nc, zmxnv; lkjdfsd; lakfjas, nxc
  </div>
  <div class="pictures">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading"
         src="1ma63N35/1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading"
         src="1ma63N35/2.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading"
         src="1ma63N35/3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading"
         src="1ma63N35/4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading"
         src="1ma63N35/5.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```